# combine perl GetoptLong with special single ARGV case?

Tags: perl, bash, scripting, parameter-passing

I am translating a shell script to a Perl script that uses Getopt::Long, and I want to keep compatibility with the case below where, if the only argument to the script is a single file, that file is used as a config file, whereas the usual is to get parameters into GetoptLong.

```
if [[ $# -eq 1 && -f $1 ]];
then 
    echo "Using config file $1"
    [...]
else 
    if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then usage "INCORRECT NUMBER OF PARAMETERS"; fi
    while getopts ":a:b:c:d:ef" opt;
    do
    [...]
```

One option is to maintain the `if/else` in the Perl script like so:

```
if (1 == @ARGV && -f $ARGV[0]) {
  # use this config file
  config_file_method($ARGV[0]);
} else {
  # use GetOptions
  GetOptions(
         'a|foo:s' => \$foo,
         'b|bar:s' => \bar,
         [...]
        );
}
```

But I wonder if this special case could be included in the GetOptions
function with some magic:

```
  GetOptions(
         'if only one element in @ARGV' => 'call config_file_method($ARGV[0])',
         'a|foo:s' => \$foo,
         'b|bar:s' => \bar,
         [...]
        );
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `==` compares numbers. Numbers are scalars, so `==` imposes are scalar context on its args. Every instance of `scalar` you have there is useless.

Comment: @ikegami, noted, I've changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything in the [Getopt::Long](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html) documentation which supports what you are looking for.

The approach I would take is to let `GetOptions` process `@ARGV`.  If anything is still in `@ARGV`, then you can assume it is the config file.  Then there is no need for the `-f` check because the `config_file_method` sub will do an `open`/`die` check anyway.

```
GetOptions(
    'a|foo:s' => \$foo,
    'b|bar:s' => \$bar,
);

config_file_method($ARGV[0]) if @ARGV;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that it's not possible. If you was passing the config_file as an option instead of an argument you could do something like that:

```
GetOptions(
    'c|config_file' => sub { config_file_method($ARGV[0]) if 1 == scalar @ARGV } ,
    'a|foo:s' => \$foo,
    'b|bar:s' => \bar,
    [...]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option in [Getopt::Long](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Getopt%3a%3aLong).

And as you've demonstrated, there's absolutely no need for one. (It didn't save you any work, yet it added complexity by inventing a new sublanguage.)